# ASP.NET Core View - passing altered output value based on user input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In my model, among other columns, I have `Status` column defined like this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public bool Status { get; set; }
```

So, it can have values only `1` or `0`.
Instead of `1` or `0` in Index view I have to show text value in rows: Activated (for 1) and Deactivited (for 0). I've done that with:

```
  <td>@(item.Status ? "Activated " : "Deactivted ")</td>
```

My question is - in Edit view, how do I show values "Activated" and "Deactivated" in drop list and on submit actually pass 1 or 0?

I have this code so far:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="Status">
            <option>Activated</option>
            <option>Deactivated</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

But this code is passing text (Activated or Deactivated) instead of 0 or 1.
So I need to insert something like `if "Activated" pass 1 othervise pass 0.`
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `value` attribute with `true` and `false` values correspondingly:

```
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="Nkz10Status">
        <option value="true">Activated</option>
        <option value="false">Deactivated</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: true / false is correct answer. Because 1 and 0 returned int which didn't fit with BIT datatype. So please change your answer ...value =True / value = False, and thank you!

Comment: @Harvey was glad to help!